# Unicode Character COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER C

Tags: unicode, icu

What is the likelihood that I'll run into [COMBINING LATIN SMALL LETTER C (U+0368)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/368/index.htm) in "real life" (besides [clever Scottish folk](https://plus.google.com/108389724193210567483/about))?

I'm asking since it's in both the [Unicode Block Combining Diacritical Marks](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/index.htm) and the [Category Mark, Nonspacing [Mn]](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/index.htm).

As a result, it seems to gets treated the same as characters such as [COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT (U+0300)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/300/index.htm) by Utilities such as the [ICU Transliterator](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) (using either the suggested `"NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC"` or a straight `"Latin-ASCII"` transliteration).

Comment: The behavior by ICU seems appropriate given the categorization - the character is meant to be a decoration on another character, with the other character being the main one. Any other usage (such as your clever Scottish) is abuse and shouldn't be expected to produce sane results.

Comment: It is not uncommon in medieval German text.  Well, the author isn't going to be upset if you don't support it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likelihood is very close to zero, but not exactly zero. You cannot prevent anyone from using a Unicode character as he likes. There is no specific information about U+0368 in the Unicode Standard, but it has definitely been defined as a combining character that will cause a symbol (c) to be displayed above the preceding character. I would expect to find it mostly in digitized forms of medieval manuscripts, or something like that.

Using it after a space character, as in the “clever” page mentioned, is not the intended use, but not invalid either. Unicode lets you use any combining mark after any character, whether it makes sense or not.

It has no canonical or compatibility decomposition, so there is no clear-cut way to deal with in a context where you cannot, or do not want to, retain the character.

Comment: Thank you, Jukka.  It was very difficult to find any information about the "intended use" of the character.   Knowing this (and with @MarkRansom's comment above), I understand that anyone wanting to spell M^cDonald would have to do it with superscripts (or other formatting) helps me decide it's not worth implementing special cases to transliterate it into a "regular" letter 'c'.

Answer (score 2):

The likelihood is utterly indeterminate except to say that if you expect it not to occur, then it will occur.